# ansible nested loop fileglob ansible dictionary with_nested

Tags: loops, dictionary, ansible, jinja2

lets suppose i have the following tree :

```
foo/
├─ bar/
│  ├─ secret/
│  │  ├─ directory_1/
│  │  │  ├─ file1
│  │  │  ├─ file2
│  │  ├─ directory_2/
│  │  │  ├─ file3
│  │  │  ├─ file4
```

I do not know what are the files and how much there is of them inside **directory_1** and **directory_2** i want to be able to loop inside of them and list them.

I have the following ansible dict :

```
my_directory_list:
  var1: secret_dir
  file:
    - directory: directory_1
      secret_name: secret_1
    - directory: directory_2
      secret_name: secret_2
```

and the following task :

```
- name: "my task"
  shell: echo ' in my directory : {{item.0.directory}} i have {{item.1}} '
  with_nested:
    - "{{my_root_directory.file}}"
    - "{{ lookup('fileglob', '/foo/bar/secret/{{item.0.directory}}') }}"
```

and the output expected :

```
in my directory directory_1 i have file1
in my directory directory_1 i have file2
in my directory directory_2 i have file3
in my directory directory_2 i have file4
```

but i cant make it work , for ansible the list is empty, i tried :

```
- "{{ lookup('fileglob', '/foo/bar/secret/{{item.0.directory}}').split(',') }}"
```

but still list empty, what am i doing wrong ? is it possible to achieve this kinda of output using ansible only ? no jinja/python ?

Thanks for the help,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, there are several syntax errors in your playbook that will prevent it from running *at all*.

### Quoting errors

If you use quotes in a YAML value, you have to quote the entire thing. So when you write:

```
- name: "my task"
  shell: echo ' in my directory : {{item.0.directory}} i have {{item.1}} '
```

That value of the `shell:` key will cause an error:

```
ERROR! We were unable to read either as JSON nor YAML, these are the errors we got from each:
JSON: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Syntax Error while loading YAML.
  mapping values are not allowed in this context
```

You need to put the entire value in quotes, like this:

```
- name: "my task"
  shell: "echo ' in my directory : {{item.0.directory}} i have {{item.1}} '"
```

I prefer to use one of YAML's block quote operators, like this:

```
- name: "my task"
  shell: >-
    echo ' in my directory : {{item.0.directory}} i have {{item.1}} '
```

That avoids having to play quote escaping games if you need to use
both double and single quotes in your command line.

### Variable substitution errors

You never nest Jinja template markers (`{{...}}`). When you write:

```
- "{{ lookup('fileglob', '/foo/bar/secret/{{item.0.directory}}') }}"
```

You end up passing the literal string `/foo/bar/secret/{{item.0.directory}}` to the `fileglob` lookup. You would instead need to write it like this:

```
- "{{ lookup('fileglob', '/foo/bar/secret/' ~ item.0.directory) }}"
```

Where `~` is the Jinja string concatenation operator. But this still
won't work, because of...

### Logic errors

The loop variable `item` isn't available in the arguments to
`with_nested` (because the loop hasn't started executing yet when the
arguments are interpreted), so even if you fix the syntax, you will
see the following failure:

```
TASK [my task] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "'item' is undefined"}
```

---

I would solve this problem by splitting the task into two separate
tasks: one to look up the files, and a second to manipulate the data
(or display it). Something like:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    my_directory_list:
      var1: secret_dir
      file:
        - directory: directory_1
          secret_name: secret_1
        - directory: directory_2
          secret_name: secret_2

  tasks:
    - name: "find files"
      find:
        path: "foo/bar/secret/{{ item.directory }}"
      register: files
      loop: "{{ my_directory_list.file }}"

    - name: "display results"
      debug:
        msg: "In my directory {{ item.0.item.directory }} I have {{ item.1.path|basename }}"
      loop: "{{ files.results|subelements('files') }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.1.path }}"
```

In the above playbook, the "find files" task uses the `find` module to
get a list of files in each directory listed in
`my_directory_list.files`. We register the results of this loop in
variable `files`. See [the documentation on the use of `register` in a
loop](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#registering-variables-with-a-loop) to understand the structure of that variable.

In the "display results" task, we iterate over the result of the first
loop using the [`subelements`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/subelements_lookup.html) filter. This effectively gives us a
flattened list of `(directory, file_path)` tuples, so we can generate
the output you're looking for.

With you example file structure, running the above playbook produces the following output:

```
PLAY [localhost] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [find files] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item={'directory': 'directory_1', 'secret_name': 'secret_1'})
ok: [localhost] => (item={'directory': 'directory_2', 'secret_name': 'secret_2'})

TASK [display results] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=foo/bar/secret/directory_1/file2) => {
    "msg": "In my directory directory_1 I have file2"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=foo/bar/secret/directory_1/file1) => {
    "msg": "In my directory directory_1 I have file1"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=foo/bar/secret/directory_2/file4) => {
    "msg": "In my directory directory_2 I have file4"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=foo/bar/secret/directory_2/file3) => {
    "msg": "In my directory directory_2 I have file3"
}

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, i will need to run some kubectl secret on the files by folder but i think i get your logic and yes you're right about the logical issue i was thinking the same .. checking and will valide once i get home , ty again